# Navigate users to the screen where they can turn off power saving mode

Tags: android, huawei-developers, xiaomi, oppo

I have tried to navigate users to power saving mode change screen using the following intent

```
Intent(Settings.ACTION_BATTERY_SAVER_SETTINGS)
```

However this will not work for manufacturers like Huawei, Xiaomi, Oppo, etc
Can anyone give me the manufacturer specific intents to navigate Power saving mode change screen.

Comment: check this out,https://stackoverflow.com/a/9530965/12709358

Comment: @ajithkumar-muthukumaran, 'ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY' is navigate to battery usage summary page. So no button to turn off power saving mode. I want to navigate user to the place where user can turn off power saving mode. 'ACTION_POWER_USAGE_SUMMARY' Intent not navigate to power saving action screen.

Comment: you need to find location for Huawei,Xiaomi Ect..  there is some apps are available you can ```Manifest``` file info it may help ,https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majeur.applicationsinfo

Comment: super go ahead.

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran what should I do after that? there are too many manufactures to cover and checking every single manufacture is not possible, so is there any other way to handle it, please?